# Are variables attached to values or are values attached to variables?

Tags: python

So I am slightly confused as to whether values are made and assigned to existing variables, variables are made and are assigned to existing values or whether they are both made and assigned to each other.

I am aware of the popular model of variables as boxes and values going into these boxes, but is this accurate relating to Python as a language? If it is not, is there a more accurate model pertaining to variables in Python to help me better understand this?

Comment: Variables are a mapping from names to values. Like the keys and values in a dict. They're not really _attached_ to values per se.

Comment: Could you add an example highlighting the difference between the two? Are there cases where you'd expect them to behave differently?

Comment: There is nothing special Python brings comparing to other languages. It's dynamically typed so you can have one type value assigned to a variable and a different type at a later point.

Comment: CPython variables are either keys in a dict or part of a symbol table. All variables act as references, under the hood, they store PyObject pointers. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: [Python Variables - Object References](https://realpython.com/python-variables/#object-references) - these might be the boxes you are looking for (the variables are not the boxes)...

Comment: Variables-as-boxes is not an accurate model for Python variables; rather, a name is a label for some value.

Comment: @tobias_k What do you mean by an example highlighting the difference? A variable is a name/container for a value which is str,int,float,list,dict,tuple,etc

Comment: Thinking of a variable as a container breaks down if you consider multiple names referring to the same object. If I write `a = b = [1,2,3]`, which box, `a` or `b`, is `[1,2,3]` in?

Comment: @Austin well, if someone is coming from C/C++ then a variable is like a location in memory, i.e. the box analogy. But yes, Python isn't different than JavaScript, Ruby, Java etc in the way it handles things, but a lot of people still learn C-style variables, which Python does not have

Comment: @chepner Yes I am aware of that but is that not different in other languages?

Comment: @JohnSmith yes for example in C, structs etc will get implicitly copied (lots of subtleties involving pointers, arrays, and padding). However, Python works the same way as most modern popular languages, i.e. JavaScript, Ruby, Java etc

Comment: I meant, what would be the practical implications of / differenes between "A being attached to B", "B attached to A", or "both attached to each other"? It is not really clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, a variable is a *pair* consisting of a name and a value, not a named location in memory.

A value can exist (albeit transiently) without a label.

A value can have more than one name associated with it.

*All* assignments simply cause a name to refer to an existing value. Even if the value is created "by" the assignment statement, you can think of the right-hand side as being a separate first step to produce an otherwise anonymous value, which *then* gets a name assigned to it. `x = [1,2,3]` first creates a list, then assigns the name `x` to that list.

Comment: Thanks, that was just the clarification I was looking for with such a bloodbath of varying comments. A well formulated and substantiated answer that has helped me, thank you.